# Downloading a png image

Tags: android, png

I need to retrieve a png image from the Internet. I have the correct URL pointing to the image, it's something like this:

[image]

So, I have my URL object like this:

```
URL url = new URL(methodThatLoadsTheStringPointingToMyURL());
```

An I can get a InputStream like this:

```
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

However, the only way I know to decode it into a Drawable is by using BitmapDrawable constructor, and that kills the PNG transparency.

Is there any way to retain PNG transparency?

Comment: I'm answering after you've accepted another answer, but isn't it better to cache the file locally, and than load it from the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

The able link must help you out to address the problem of retaining the Transparency.
Its a standard Library to read and write png image data